# Cant get arrays to keep value in class

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, variables

When I use the object function `set_and_make_variable` I send it a name and value which both work correctly. However then when I go to use show `current_variables` it acts like I never set the values for both `integers`, and `integers_names`. I thought you could modify the variables arrays from the functions associated with the class without references or pointers.
Am I not correct?

```
void reset_name(string *variable_names)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        variable_names[i] = "";
    }
}
void reset_int_value(int *variable_value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        variable_value[i] = 0;
    }
}
int find_next(string variable_names[100]) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (variable_names[i] == "")
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}


//*****************************************************************
class variables_integers
{
public:
    string integer_names[100];
    int integers[100];

    variables_integers(void);
    void set_and_make_variable(string, int);
    void show_current_variables(void);

};

variables_integers::variables_integers(void)
{
    reset_int_value(integers);
    reset_name(integer_names);
}

void variables_integers::show_current_variables(void)
{
    cout << "INTEGERS:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < (find_next(integer_names)); i++)
    {
        cout << integer_names[i] << " = " << integers[i] << endl;
    }
}

void variables_integers::set_and_make_variable(string name, int value)
{
    cout << name << "   " << value << endl;
    cout << find_next(integer_names) << endl;
    integers[find_next(integer_names)] = value;
    integer_names[find_next(integer_names)] = name;
}


//*** added code ******
bool operations_and_declerations(string parsed_input[3000], variables variable)
{
    if (parsed_input[0] == "int")
    {
        if (parsed_input[2] == "=")
        {
            variable.integers.set_and_make_variable(parsed_input[1], atoi(parsed_input[3].c_str()));
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if (parsed_input[0] == "string")
    {
        return true;
    }
    //else if (parsed_input[0] ==)
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any errors that jump out. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Which is the code you use to call the member functions of the class?Maybe the problem lies there

Comment: did you try to step over this code with debugger?

Comment: I added the code at the bottom. variable is the parent object that holds the integer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `operations_and_declerations()`, you sent your `variables` parameter by value. Hence, the function created a local copy, and only modified that local copy.

You can fix the problem by sending it the parameter by reference. Just modify the function name to:
`bool operations_and_declerations(string parsed_input[3000], variables & variable)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I had done that. Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes.